# How to implement vidyo.io in ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, phonegap, vidyo

I am trying to implement vidyo.io in ionic3 using native android plugin but i am not getting success, is there anyone has implemented vidyo.io for video calling.

Thanks,
Jagdish

Answer (score 0):

Here is Vidyo's sample Cordova plugin showing how to integrate Vidyo.io:
https://github.com/Vidyo/VidyoIOCordovaPlugin